# How to identify build_id/name of a job generated by Jenkins Remote Trigger

Tags: jenkins

How does the application get back the BUILD_ID or BUILD_NUMBER that their HTTP Post has caused when submitting the build request by performing an HTTP Post to the Jenkins CI Job using `.../buildWithParameters?token=TOKEN` to kick off a build?

For example, if I have 6 applications running that each kick off the same Jenkins CI job, each build would get a different build_id, but how does each application know which particular build_id corresponds to their trigger request?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Retrieve id of remotely triggered jenkins job](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24507262/retrieve-id-of-remotely-triggered-jenkins-job)

Answer (score 2):

Once they trigger a build, get the build_id and store it

`.../api/xml?xpath=//lastBuild/number/text()`

Will get you the build number of the currently running job. Assuming your job goes faster then a few seconds, using the lastBuild/number/text() will get you the build number that you can then use later to retrieve whatever you want.

Comment: Hi George, thanks for the reply.  Would there still be race conditions to worry about amongst all the jobs?

Comment: As soon as the job is started that build number is valid, no race condition that I could see, and that is how I kick some of my builds.

Comment: The problem is when two builds are submitted simultaneously. lastBuild will no longer point to the build you've submitted.