# Retrieve id of remotely triggered jenkins job

Tags: jenkins

I am triggering a parameterized Jenkins from from outside of jenkins via a http POST request:

I have enabled in the job configuration that the job can be triggered from outside and i can really trigger it by sending jenkins a request with a content like this:

POST
http://myJenkins.com/myJob/buildWithParameters?token=MYTOKEN
Parameter: SCREEN_SIZE: 27

Triggering the job creation returns a successfull 201 CREATED http response.

My problem is that i dont know the id of the build job that was created. I want to monitor the state of the job. In order to do that i need to know the id. Otherwise, if i just take the latest build of that job, i could take wrong job.

Is there a reliable way to get the id of the created job?

Comment: Here is the shell script i use for the same https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29150106/jenkins-rest-api-get-a-build-number-of-a-job-that-just-started/74162441#74162441

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Update:**

The [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28524219/3583500) was added ~8 months after mine. I was unaware of the *location* header in the response at the time. That does sound like a good option for some cases. That said, based on the caveats in the answer and the comments (especially around *parameterized* builds), it appears that this answer still has some utility for some cases.

**Original answer:**

Unfortunately, they don't make this as straightforward as it could be. i.e. by, say, returning a *JSON* response with information like an *id*.

However, I believe a solid, though certainly non-trivial, workaround to that would be to leverage the *cause* parameter in the URL you use to trigger the build, and within that cause, add *unique text* that you can later parse to determine that you triggered it from your automation.

To further uniqueify the specific job, in case multiple are running around the same time, even from your automation, also include a *unique ID* of some type (it could simply be a sequence ID from your *RDBMS* or similar) inside of the cause parameter.

Then, you can use the *JSON API* to get information about the *job* you're remotely triggering. Again, it's somewhat indirect, but doable:

Hit a URL of the form:

```
http://<server>:<port>/job/<jobname>/lastBuild/api/json
```

You can add `?pretty=true` to pretty-print it within the browser for better human readability.

That will get you the *JSON* of the last build. It will contain the *causes* attribute within the *actions* attribute, and in there (in another nested attribute named *shortDescription*) you would find the *cause* parameter you added, if this was one of the builds you triggered.

You could parse out both the special static text, and your generated ID to see if they match. If they do, you can then get the *Jenkins id* out of the *JSON* as well (search for *buildNumber*, which is nested).

If that build is either not triggered by your automation at all, or was, but the ID doesn't match, you can repeat the process for the *N - 1 build* until you find what you're looking for.

That JSON would be of the form:

```
http://<server>:<port>/job/<jobname>/<buildNumber>/api/json
```

Comment: can you please elaborate on how to add the `cause` parameter? I've search for Jenkins documentation and could not find any reference to this parameter.

Comment: It's a parameter that you specify in the URL you use to trigger the build via *curl* or similar. e.g. add the parameter `cause=foo_100` to the URL.

Comment: Great response! There is potential for a race condition where your triggered job execution is still in the queue when you are searching through the builds history for the unique ID. You can avoid this by using the Location that is included in the 201 created response and basically wait for it to leave the queue.

Answer (score 53):

Since Jenkins 1.519, enqueuing a build responds with a URL in the `Location`, pointing you to an item in the build queue:

```
$ nc localhost 8666
POST /jenkins/job/morgRemote/buildWithParameters?jenkins_status=1&jenkins_sleep=20&token=morgRemote HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8666

HTTP/1.1 201 Created
Location: http://localhost:8666/jenkins/queue/item/39/
Content-Length: 0
Server: Jetty(winstone-2.8)
```

Now if you add `api/json` (or `api/xml` and so on) to the end of it (so in this example it would be `http://localhost:8666/jenkins/queue/item/39/api/json`) then you will get a document that will contain build id for the given job. For json the retrieved object has `executable` attribute, which in  turn has `number` and `url` attributes. `number` is the build id for the given job (35 here) and `url` is the jenkins build page url.

```
{
  "actions" : [
    {
      "parameters" : [
        {
          "name" : "jenkins_status",
          "value" : "1"
        },
        {
          "name" : "jenkins_sleep",
          "value" : "20"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "causes" : [
        {
          "shortDescription" : "Started by remote host 127.0.0.1",
          "addr" : "127.0.0.1",
          "note" : null
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "blocked" : false,
  "buildable" : false,
  "id" : 39,
  "inQueueSince" : 1423993879845,
  "params" : "\njenkins_status=1\njenkins_sleep=20",
  "stuck" : false,
  "task" : {
    "name" : "morgRemote",
    "url" : "http://localhost:8666/jenkins/job/morgRemote/",
    "color" : "red"
  },
  "url" : "queue/item/39/",
  "why" : null,
  "cancelled" : false,
  "executable" : {
    "number" : 35,
    "url" : "http://localhost:8666/jenkins/job/morgRemote/35/"
  }
}
```

be aware of 2 things:

- inactive items in the build queue are garbage collected after few minutes, so you should retrieve build id ASAP
- by default it takes few seconds between item is added to the queue until it gets build id. During this time `executable` and `canceled` attributes will be missing and `why` will be not null. You can change this behavior in "Advanced Project Options" of your job config by modifying "Quiet period" setting or in the jenkins global configuration.

:

```
  ...
  "url" : "queue/item/39/",
  "why" : "In the quiet period. Expires in 2.4 sec",
  "timestamp" : 1423993879845
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! This partially worked for me. I'm on v1.559 and if I have a NON parameterized build and use /build I get the location. When I use buildWithParameters I get an error... expected. On a parameterized build I do not get the correct location. If I use /build I get the job url and if I use buildWithParameters I get nothing in the Location header. Any ideas?

Comment: Regarding retrieving the build id ASAP because the queue item will get garbage collected see this issue: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-31039

Comment: "by default it takes few seconds between item is added to the queue until it gets build id" - actually it could take seconds, hours, or days! Until Jenkins finds and assigns an executor to run the the job, the job has no build number.

Comment: FYI: I am on **Jenkins ver. 2.138.4** with a quiet period of 1 second configured. the "executable" part would not appear if in the quiet period, and 1.5s delay was insufficient (`"why"` would be `"???"`). adding a 5s delay before reading the url solved it.

Answer (score 3):

Turns out builds have the original queue ID. Furthermore you can query for only the build with your queue Id and poll it until you get a result because 404 should normally imply it is queued.

Pull the Queue ID off the Location header, e.g. 39

```
/jenkins/queue/item/39/
```

Repeatedly query for a build with that queue number until you get an answer

```
"http://{jenkins}job/{job}/api/xml?tree=builds[number,queueId]&xpath=//build[queueId=\"{queueId}\"]";

<build>
  <number>411</number>
  <queueId>39</queueId>
</build>
```

From this result you can pull the build number with the xpath `/build/number/text()`

(Note I could not use `&xpath=//build[queueId={queueId}]/number/text()` in the url because `"primitive XPath result sets forbidden; implement jenkins.security.SecureRequester"`)

It is equally as lame as polling the queue api for an "executable" build. One advantage is the endpoint will persist longer - until the build is deleted, compared to an arbitrary time (which seems to be about 5 minutes).

Comment: Thanks for that! Also the xpath stuff makes things a lot easier, don't need a JSON parser to find the right bit of data.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to use Java Jenkins api to achieve what you are looking for.
https://github.com/jenkinsci/java-client-api

Sample Code:

```
JenkinsServer jenkinsServer = new JenkinsServer(newURI("http://yourJenkinsServer:8080/"));
JobWithDetails smokeTestJob = jenkinsServer.getJob("YourJobName");        
Map<String,String> jobParams = new HashMap<String,String>();
QueueReference queueReference = smokeTestJob.build(jobParams);

do {
  Thread.sleep(2000L);
  queueItem = jenkinsServer.getQueueItem(queueReference);
  log("Job still in queue"+queueItem.getExecutable());
  } while (queueItem.getExecutable() == null);

Build build = jenkinsServer.getBuild(queueItem);

while(build.details().isBuilding()){
  log("Job still running");
  Thread.sleep(10000L);
}

log("Result="+build.details().getResult());
```

Answer (score 1):

Wanted to add to morgwai answer using the Location header.

I just solved this problem. The key after the Location header is to poll the job queue entry till it has an 'executable' entry that gives the job number that has been started.

I give the full answer to a similar question that I saw first that did not completely answer the problem:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/48531874/9291603

JSON from Jenkins job queue entry with the executable entry:

```
{
    "_class": "hudson.model.Queue$LeftItem",
    "actions": [
        {
            "_class": "hudson.model.CauseAction",
            "causes": [
                {
                    "_class": "hudson.model.Cause$RemoteCause",
                    "addr": "10.20.30.60",
                    "note": null,
                    "shortDescription": "Started by remote host 10.20.30.60"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "blocked": false,
    "buildable": false,
    "cancelled": false,
    "executable": {
        "_class": "org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun",
        "number": 45,
        "url": "http://192.168.115.187:8080/job/rf_systest/45/"
    },
    "id": 95,
    "inQueueSince": 1517342648136,
    "params": "",
    "stuck": false,
    "task": {
        "_class": "org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowJob",
        "color": "blue_anime",
        "name": "rf_systest",
        "url": "http://192.168.115.187:8080/job/rf_systest/"
    },
    "url": "queue/item/95/",
    "why": null
}
```