# How to Remotely start jenkins build and get back result transactionally?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I had a request a to create a java client and start jenkins build for a specific job; and get back the result of that build.
The problem is, the system is used by multiple users and their build might messed up altogether. Also the get latest build my retrieve me the previous finished build instead of current one. Is there anyway to do build/get result transactionally?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a way to get true transactional functionality (in the way that, say, *Postgres* is transactional), however, I think you can prevent collisions amongst multiple users by doing the following:

Have your build wrapped around a script (*bash*, *Python*, or similar) which takes out an **exclusive** lock on a *semfile* before the build and releases it after its done. That is, a file which serves as a semaphore that the build process must be able to exclusively lock in order to be able to proceed.

That way, if you have a build in progress, and another user triggers one, the in-progress build will have the *semfile* locked, and the 2nd one will block waiting for the exclusive lock on that file, getting the lock only once the 1st build is complete and has released the lock on the file.

Also, to be able to refer to each remote build after the fact, I would recommend you refer to my previous post [Retrieve id of remotely triggered jenkins job](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24507262/retrieve-id-of-remotely-triggered-jenkins-job/24521780#24521780).