# Check Jenkins job status after triggering a build remotely

Tags: jenkins, build, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-cli

I have a script to trigger a job on Jenkins remotely using a token. Here is my script:

```
JENKINS_URL='http://jenkins.myserver.com/jenkins'
JOB_NAME='job/utilities/job/my_job'
JOB_TOKEN='my_token'

curl "${JENKINS_URL}/${JOB_NAME}/buildWithParameters?token=${JOB_TOKEN}"
```

**After I run it, I get following response:**

```
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 10.5.187.225...
* Connected to jenkins.myserver.com (10.5.187.225) port 80 (#0)
> GET /jenkins/job/utilities/job/my_job/buildWithParameters?token=my_token HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.37.1
> Host: jenkins.myserver.com
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 201 Created
* Server nginx/1.6.2 is not blacklisted
< Server: nginx/1.6.2
< Date: Tue, 03 Feb 2015 23:40:47 GMT
< Content-Length: 0
< Location: http://jenkins.myserver.com/jenkins/queue/item/91/
< Connection: keep-alive
< Cache-Control: private
< Expires: Wed, 31 Dec 1969 16:00:00 PST
< 
* Connection #0 to host jenkins.myserver.com left intact
```

I noticed that it returns the queue url in the header: http://jenkins.myserver.com/jenkins/queue/item/91. But I don't know how I should use this return url.

1) I am wondering if anyone knows how I can check the status for the job that I just created?

2) Since the above response does not return the job #, I can't really use this api call:

```
curl http://jenkins.myserver.com/jenkins/job/utilities/job/my_job/8/api/json
```

to check for status. So where can I get the job name and job number after I get the location url from the above response?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you trigger a job, the job is placed into the queue. The actual build is created only when it starts running and at that point the build gets a build number. If all your executors are busy, it can sometimes take a long time before the build is created and starts running.

The only way to get the build number when triggering a job, is to use the "build" command of the [Jenkins CLI](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Jenkins+CLI). If you use the -w option, the command will not return until the build starts and then it will print "Started build #N"

You do not actually need the java cli.jar, just an ssh client is enough. See https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Jenkins+SSH

Other than that there is no known solution. You might be able to search through the builds and find a one that was triggered around the time your triggered the job, but that's a lot of work.

Comment: @sti does this limitation still exist? It's a major downside to using the Rest api where the CLI is not a practical alternative

Comment: This is not the only way to get the build number. Keep reading further answers

Comment: Downvoted because this is simply incorrect. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/48531874/1011280 below for an answer that uses the remote HTTP API.

Answer (score 40):

I solved this problem using polling of the Jenkins server.  When a job is started remotely the return headers has the job queue URL.  Using this one can make more API calls to get status.

Steps:

- start the job
- parse return 'Location' header
- poll the queue looking for job to start

  - job queue entry will have an 'executable' entry in its json or xml with job number once it starts
- poll the job status waiting for a result

I used python and the Requests module to do this

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import requests
import re
import sys 
import json
import time

# secs for polling Jenkins API
#
QUEUE_POLL_INTERVAL = 2 
JOB_POLL_INTERVAL = 20
OVERALL_TIMEOUT = 3600 # 1 hour

# job specifics: should be passed in
auth_token = 'buildmaster:173223588624f980c3AAA68d4d8efe0c'
jenkins_uri = '192.168.115.187:8080'
job_name = 'rf_systest'
build_token = 'rf_systest_auth_token'

# start the build
#
start_build_url = 'http://{}@{}/job/{}/build?token={}'.format(
        auth_token, jenkins_uri, job_name, build_token)
r = requests.post(start_build_url)

# from return headers get job queue location
#
m = re.match(r"http.+(queue.+)\/", r.headers['Location'])
if not m:
    # To Do: handle error
    print "Job starte request did not have queue location"
    sys.exit(1)

# poll the queue looking for job to start
#
queue_id = m.group(1)
job_info_url = 'http://{}@{}/{}/api/json'.format(auth_token, jenkins_uri, queue_id)
elasped_time = 0 
print '{} Job {} added to queue: {}'.format(time.ctime(), job_name, job_info_url)
while True:
    l = requests.get(job_info_url)
    jqe = l.json()
    task = jqe['task']['name']
    try:
        job_id = jqe['executable']['number']
        break
    except:
        #print "no job ID yet for build: {}".format(task)
        time.sleep(QUEUE_POLL_INTERVAL)
        elasped_time += QUEUE_POLL_INTERVAL

    if (elasped_time % (QUEUE_POLL_INTERVAL * 10)) == 0:
        print "{}: Job {} not started yet from {}".format(time.ctime(), job_name, queue_id)

# poll job status waiting for a result
#
job_url = 'http://{}@{}/job/{}/{}/api/json'.format(auth_token, jenkins_uri, job_name, job_id)
start_epoch = int(time.time())
while True:
    print "{}: Job started URL: {}".format(time.ctime(), job_url)
    j = requests.get(job_url)
    jje = j.json()
    result = jje['result']
    if result == 'SUCCESS':
        # Do success steps
        print "{}: Job: {} Status: {}".format(time.ctime(), job_name, result)
        break
    elif result == 'FAILURE':
        # Do failure steps
        print "{}: Job: {} Status: {}".format(time.ctime(), job_name, result)
        break
    elif result == 'ABORTED':
        # Do aborted steps
        print "{}: Job: {} Status: {}".format(time.ctime(), job_name, result)
        break
    else:
        print "{}: Job: {} Status: {}. Polling again in {} secs".format(
                time.ctime(), job_name, result, JOB_POLL_INTERVAL)

    cur_epoch = int(time.time())
    if (cur_epoch - start_epoch) > OVERALL_TIMEOUT:
        print "{}: No status before timeout of {} secs".format(OVERALL_TIMEOUT)
        sys.exit(1)

    time.sleep(JOB_POLL_INTERVAL)
```

Output:

```
Tue Jan 30 16:24:08 2018: Job rf_systest added to queue: http://buildmaster:173223588624f980c344668d4d8efe0c@192.168.115.187:8080/queue/item/164/api/json
Tue Jan 30 16:24:39 2018: Job rf_systest not started yet from queue/item/164
Tue Jan 30 16:25:00 2018: Job started URL: http://buildmaster:173223588624f980c344668d4d8efe0c@192.168.115.187:8080/job/rf_systest/79/api/json
Tue Jan 30 16:25:01 2018: Job: rf_systest Status: None. Polling again in 20 secs
Tue Jan 30 16:25:21 2018: Job started URL: http://buildmaster:173223588624f980c344668d4d8efe0c@192.168.115.187:8080/job/rf_systest/79/api/json
Tue Jan 30 16:25:21 2018: Job: rf_systest Status: None. Polling again in 20 secs
Tue Jan 30 16:25:41 2018: Job started URL: http://buildmaster:173223588624f980c344668d4d8efe0c@192.168.115.187:8080/job/rf_systest/79/api/json
Tue Jan 30 16:25:41 2018: Job: rf_systest Status: None. Polling again in 20 secs
Tue Jan 30 16:26:01 2018: Job started URL: http://buildmaster:173223588624f980c344668d4d8efe0c@192.168.115.187:8080/job/rf_systest/79/api/json
Tue Jan 30 16:26:01 2018: Job: rf_systest Status: None. Polling again in 20 secs
Tue Jan 30 16:26:21 2018: Job started URL: http://buildmaster:173223588624f980c344668d4d8efe0c@192.168.115.187:8080/job/rf_systest/79/api/json
Tue Jan 30 16:26:21 2018: Job: rf_systest Status: SUCCESS
```

JSON from a Jenkins queue once its job has started:

```
{
    "_class": "hudson.model.Queue$LeftItem",
    "actions": [
        {
            "_class": "hudson.model.CauseAction",
            "causes": [
                {
                    "_class": "hudson.model.Cause$RemoteCause",
                    "addr": "10.20.30.60",
                    "note": null,
                    "shortDescription": "Started by remote host 10.20.30.60"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "blocked": false,
    "buildable": false,
    "cancelled": false,
    "executable": {
        "_class": "org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun",
        "number": 45,
        "url": "http://192.168.115.187:8080/job/rf_systest/45/"
    },
    "id": 95,
    "inQueueSince": 1517342648136,
    "params": "",
    "stuck": false,
    "task": {
        "_class": "org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowJob",
        "color": "blue_anime",
        "name": "rf_systest",
        "url": "http://192.168.115.187:8080/job/rf_systest/"
    },
    "url": "queue/item/95/",
    "why": null
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this! It is super useful. One quick question, what is the '"why":null'? I am looking for a way to pass a percentage result value once a job is completed, do you know if that is possible via the response json? Thanks again.

Comment: This one should be the accepted answer, locate the queue id and query it API and finally get build-id. http://jenkinsurl/queue/item/43815 will return 404, however, http://jenkinsurl/queue/item/43815/api/json will return the build number.

Comment: any reasons why I am getting 404 with the api/json suffix as well?

Comment: @khc this happens when the job is being scheduled and emptied from the queue, queue id is ephemeral and should be used asap.

Comment: Tip: You can reduce the time you spend in the `while True:` by setting the "quiet period" of your job to zero if you don't need it. *(mine was defaulted to 5s)*

Comment: I am getting: `c:\temp>py test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\temp\test.py", line 3, in <module>
    import requests
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'`

Comment: 1 hour ! wy wy wy

Answer (score 7):

I had similar problem to get state with rest api only.
this was my solution (it is a **weak and not stable** solution!):

```sh
#Ex. http://jenkins.com/job/test
JOB_URL="${JENKINS_URL}/job/${JOB_NAME}"

#here you can ask for next build job number
function getNextBuildNr(){
  curl --silent ${JOB_URL}/api/json | grep -Po '"nextBuildNumber":\K\d+'
}    

# this will request the Status of job
function getBuildState(){
  buildNr=$1
  curl --silent ${JOB_URL}/${buildNr}/api/json | grep -Po '"result":\s*"\K\w+'
}

#this will wait for your Job state, by polling Jenkins every second
function waitForJob() {
  buildNr=$1
  state=""

  while [ "${state}" == "" ]
  do
     sleep 1
     state=$(getBuildState ${buildNr})
     echo -n '.'
  done

  echo -e "\n"
}

#now you can run and build
BUILD_NR=$(getNextBuildNr)

# input here your code/function to trigger the job

waitForJob ${BUILD_NR}
BUILD_STATE=$(getBuildState ${BUILD_NR})
echo "$BUILD_STATE"
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use Jenkins API for this. A sample Python script:

```
import json
import requests
import time



job_name = "testjob" .  #Give your job name here


def jenkins_job_status(job_name):

        try:
                url  = "https://your_jenkins_endpoint/job/%s/lastBuild/api/json" %job_name   #Replace 'your_jenkins_endpoint' with your Jenkins URL
                while True:
                        data = requests.get(url).json()
                        if data['building']:
                                time.sleep(60)
                        else:
                                if data['result'] == "SUCCESS":

                                        print "Job is success"
                                        return True
                                else:
                                        print "Job status failed"
                                        return False


        except Exception as e:
                print str(e)
                return False




if __name__ == "__main__":

        if jenkins_job_status(job_name):

                print "Put your autmation here for 'job is success' condition"

        else:
                print "Put your autmation here for 'job is failed' condition"
```

Refer http://www.easyaslinux.com/tutorials/devops/how-to-check-build-status-of-jenkins-job-using-python-script/ for detailed explanation

Answer (score 2):

For the ones who need to trigger a remote Jenkins job from another Jenkins, here is quite a good solution that allows triggering a remote job and checking its status: https://github.com/jenkinsci/parameterized-remote-trigger-plugin/blob/master/README_PipelineConfiguration.md

It is as simple as that:

```html
def handle = triggerRemoteJob job: 'https://myjenkins:8080/job/JobWithoutParams', auth: TokenAuth(apiToken: '<theApiToken>', userName: '<userName>'), parameters: 'param1=abc\nparam2=xyz'
```

Answer (score 0):

A fully groovy enabled solution would be something like following:

```
 import groovy.json.JsonSlurper



    while(true){
            sh """
                   curl -X POST -u "admin:xxx" "https://another-jenkins.com/job/jobName/build"
               """

               def response = sh(script: """ curl -X GET -u "admin:xxx" "https://another-jenkins.com/job/jobName/lastBuild/api/json" """, returnStdout: true)

               def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper()
               def obj = jsonSlurper.parseText(response)

               if (!obj.building){

                   if(obj.result=="FAILURE"){
                    println("remote jenkins failing")
                       //throw new Exception("QA JENKINS returns failure.")
                   }
                   break;
               }
                
                sleep(3000)
       }
```