# How to trigger a Jenkins Job from outside and receive the status of build

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I need to trigger a Job from another Scheduler and want to receive the status of the triggered Job after it finishes. 
Sure it would be possible to create a status file or such, but it would be convenient to trigger the Job from a script or per httpRequest and wait for some kind of exit or return code.
Is that possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check Jenkins job status after triggering a build remotely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28311030/check-jenkins-job-status-after-triggering-a-build-remotely)

Comment: Yep, the answer is in there.

Comment: The Aswer seems to be Jenkins CLI

Answer (score 0):

For this, you have to use `Build Authorization Token Root` Jenkins plugin

It will allow you to run Jenkins build remotely.

[Check this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4atnk.png)

Please check my article : https://medium.com/appgambit/trigger-jenkins-job-from-slack-5b07b6131e25

But yes you can skip slack integration and just use API for triggering particular job.

Or if you want to run your job after another job is complete or success you have to use "Build after other projects are built"

[Build after other projects are built](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M2YZc.png)