# How to get or pass other job build duration to current job

Tags: jenkins

I have two test jobs(say job A and job B), and will run the test report job(say job C) after job A and job B finished, and will send test report with the email template which I want to contain job A and job B duration string. So how to get the job A and job B duration string in job C?

Answer (score 0):

You can curl the api for the json for the build to get the duration and convert it to human readable format:

`https://<jenkins-url>:<port>/job/<job-name>/lastBuild/api/json`

If you want to see a 'pretty' version of the json, you can append the below to the above url:

`?pretty=true`

There will be a `duration` variable within the json that will contain the time spent building (not sure if it highlights any 'waiting' time).

Some examples of people doing similar things:

- [Retrieve id of remotely triggered jenkins job](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24507262/retrieve-id-of-remotely-triggered-jenkins-job)
- https://santoshbandage.wordpress.com/2017/09/04/jenkins-api-to-get-build-details/